# Get parameter of a class constructor using reflection

Tags: c#, unit-testing, reflection

I am writing unit tests for a class, and I would like to have individual exception messages when checking each parameter for null.

What I don't know is how to implement `GetParameterNameWithReflection` method below:

```
public class struct SUT
{
    public SUT(object a, object b, object c)
    {
        if (a == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(a));
        }

        // etc. for remaining args

        // actual constructor code
    }    
}

[TextFixture]
public class SutTests
{
    [Test]
    public void constructor_shouldCheckForFirstParameterNull()
    {
        var ex = Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>(new Sut(null, new object(), new object()));

        string firstParameterName = GetParameterNameWithReflection(typeof(SUT);)

        Assert.AreEqual(firstParameterName, ex.ParamName);
    }
}
```

As a bonus, comments on the appropriateness of this type of testing are much welcome!

Comment: What is this unit test meant to protect against happening in the future?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Well that's the million dollar question. I am chronically struggling with figuring out good approaches to testing, with the ultimate goal of "going full TDD", but this type of questions induce quite a lot of analysis paralysis to be honest. The truth is: currently I just feel compelled to do these tests, but I don't feel sure at all of the "why"... That is, currently I don't have a decent answer to your question, I think :o(

Comment: The most common maintenance error that this sort of test *used* to be good for was "They've renamed the parameter but forgotten to update the literal in the exception message" but you're already guarding against that by using `nameof`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
static string GetFirstParameterNameWithReflection(Type type)
{
    return type.GetConstructors().Single().GetParameters().First().Name;
}
```

This asserts that there is exactly one constructor, gets the parameters, asserts there is at least one such and returns the name.

Comment: beat me to it :-)

Comment: @Ipsit whatever your thoughts on the name (edit): it was based on the code *in the question*

Answer (score 2):

This method will return the first parameter name of the first constructor. You could expand on this for dealing with multiple constructors and different parameters. It uses the [ParameterInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.parameterinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2) class.

```
    public string GetFirstParameterNameWithReflection(Type t)
    {
        return t.GetConstructors()[0].GetParameters()[0].Name;
    }
```

Comment: @Ipsit whatever your thoughts on the name (edit): it was based on the code *in the question*